# Why `as` operator might throw nasty EAccessViolation instead of normal EIntfCastError?

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide, toolsapi

I've made highly experimental and unstable IDE add-in, which causes extremely nasty A/V at IDE shutdown (breaks recent projects feature, grr!). I finally narrowed it down to the specific destructor:

```
destructor TMyAddIn.Destroy;
begin
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  { BUG is here, causes A/V at shutdown }
  (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAMessageServices).AddTitleMessage('Goodbye');
  {$ENDIF}

  { ... }
  { finalizing stuff }
  { ... }

   inherited;
end;
```

A/V exception happens on `read of address 0x00000008`.

I've added more defences to the problematic statement:

```
  if Assigned(BorlandIDEServices) then    { passes }
    if Supports(BorlandIDEServices, IOTAMessageServices) then   { fails }
     (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAMessageServices).AddTitleMessage('Goodbye');
```

... and figured out what (1) pointer is still not `nil` (2) `QueryInterface` still works (3) desired interface no longer present. Given that everything looks normal, I expect friendly `EIntfCastError`. But why I've got A/V instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that either

1. `BorlandIDEServices` itself is not nil but is also not valid anymore
2. `BorlandIDEServices` is valid, but its internal `IOTAMessageServices` implementation is not.

Those could account for a `read of address 0x00000008` error.

What you should do instead is obtain the `IOTAMessageServices` interface earlier in your add-in's lifetime and hold on to it, that way it is still valid in your destructor due to reference counting, eg:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
private
  MsgSvc: IOTAMessageServices;
{$ENDIF}

constructor TMyAddIn.Create;
begin
  inherited;

  { ... }
  { initializing stuff }
  { ... }

  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  MsgSvc := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAMessageServices;
  MsgSvc.AddTitleMessage('Hello');
  {$ENDIF}
end;

destructor TMyAddIn.Destroy;
begin
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  MsgSvc.AddTitleMessage('Goodbye');
  {$ENDIF}

  { ... }
  { finalizing stuff }
  { ... }

   inherited;
end;
```

Comment: That might not be enough to keep it valid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why?

Comment: Well not all interface lifetime is controlled by the ref count. It seems plausible that some of these interfaces are not managed by ref count. Should be possible to check.